# Browser isn't showing image

Tags: html, css

when i change path of imag.Browser doesnot show image 
working code

```
body {
background-image: url("D:\main.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position : center;
background-attachment : fixed ;
}
```

same code but changing path of image does not show image in browser  .Not Working

```
body {
background-image: url("D:\Source_Code\HTML\Adventure Time\main.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position : center;
background-attachment : fixed ;
}
```

Comment: Should the path you point to actually exist, you might want to escape that space. Consider taking some time to state your question in as clear and simple language as possible while also avoiding spelling and grammatical mistakes. That way your question gets better, and more, answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should give the url `path` from the current css file and not from the root of you computer. Also it's slash not backslash.

For example if your css file that contains this is in `adventure-time` directory do : `background-image: url("./main.jpg");`

Comment: It's not that one needs to give a relative path, absolute path can also be given.

Comment: But that's a bad practice if you are on local and then put it on prod all your path are dead. Better be relative from the current project folder.

Comment: @Sahil absolute paths are fine **if you are running in a webserver**. Asolute paths with the windows craps `D:`, `\ `, etc, it's not for websites. It's for funny only.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, I was just telling that both are possible.

Comment: Note that everybody uses a different operating system, and nobody will have the same folder structure and the images in the hard disk. OP needs to learn first before coding.

Comment: @Sahil OK, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving virtual path instead of physical path.
e.g. 
background-image: url("/HTML/Adventure Time/main.jpg");

Answer (score 0):

The reason most urls are relative is because that absolute urls will work albeit they do depend on the operating system. Which is not desired for maintainability.

To explain a relative url (since your relative url seems to be working for you) i made this example. I wil use the following file structure.:

Your webpages are in ./myWebsite/Pages
your CSS is in ./myWebsite/CSS
the images are in ./myWebsite/Images

Then the url of the image would be as follows:

```
background-image: url("./Images/main.jpg");
```

Breakdown of the url:

The url is made up of different parts to be simple. The first part would be the "./". This is simply to say something like "parent directory".

So the parent directory of the file which this line of code is in(./myWebsite/CSS/stylesheet.css) would be "./myWebsite/".

Then the next part is "Images/". This means something like; "select folder 'Images' ".

So now we navigated to the parent directory and then selected the folder where the images are located. The only thing left to do is to select the image, which is done by specifying its name and extension; "main.jpg".

Keep in mind this is a basic explanation